# How to add and use custom js in admin configuration creating custom module

Tags: magento2

I am creating custom module. I want to add js file in admin configuration. How can i include and use js in magento 2.x.

Answer (score 4):

You try following step to add js in admin:
Create file **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Vendor_ModuleName::js/yourjs.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/yourjs.js**

```
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'mage/translate',
    ],
    function ($) {
     //add your code 
    }
);
```

Comment: your welcome :-)

Comment: in the view source file is showing but its showing as blank, any reason behind it ?

Answer (score 3):

As per magento 2 standards, you will required requirejs-config.js to add custom javascript
Create requirejs-config.js in app/code/vendor/module-name/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customscript:'Vendor_ModuleName::js/custom'
        }
    }
};
```

then create custom.js :
app/code/Vendor/modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js

Comment: i need to load this js in admin configuration section not in frontend.
and how to call this script file?

Comment: Please add requirejs-config.js in adminthtml folder in place of frontend folder and create js directory and custom.js file

Comment: it is not working for me.
something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Load js file using the requirejs-config.js

app/code/BA/BStore/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

requirejs-config.js

```
   var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            loadcatalogs:'BA_BasysStore/js/loadcatalogs'
        }
    }
};
```

app/code/BA/BStore/view/adminhtml/web/js/loadcatalogs.js

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    return function(config) {
        $("#division_id").on('change', function() {
            var divisionId = $("#b_division_id").val();
            $.ajax({
            url: config.ajaxUrlValue,
            type: "POST",
            data: { divisionId:divisionId },
            showLoader: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
              console.log(response);            
            }
        });      
    });
}
});
```

app/code/BA/BStore/view/adminhtml/templates/loadjs.phtml

```
<?php
    $viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
    $ajaxUrl = $viewModel->getAjaxUrl();
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "loadcatalogs": {
            "ajaxUrlValue": "<?= __($ajaxUrl)?>"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

app/code/BA/BStore/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <container name="basys_load_js" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="basys_load_js">
                <block name="basysloadjs.viewmodel" template="BA_BStore::loadjs.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">BA\BStore\ViewModel\LoadajaxUrl</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/BA/BStore/ViewModel/LoadajaxUrl.php

```
<?php
namespace BA\BStore\ViewModel;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class LoadajaxUrl implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
   
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl().'admin/loadcatalogs/index/index';
    }
}
```